# Vmatrix not showing left line in table environment

Tags: tables, matrices

I am trying to put a matrix determinant into a table, but the left line of the matrix does not show up:
[image]

Can you help me get the left line to show up in the determinant matrix?  Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,x11names,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{blue!10}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\rowcolor{blue!50}
Row & $z^{0}$      & $z^{1}$      & $z^{2}$     & $z^{3}$     & $z^{4}$     & $z^{5}$      & $z^{6}$      \\
1   & 0.01822 & -0.0891 & 0.5265 & -0.825 & 0      & -0.25   & 1       \\
2   & 1       & -0.25   & 0      & -0.825 & 0.5265 & -0.0891 & 0.01822 \\
3   & $\begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & 1 \\
         1 & 0.01822
       \end{vmatrix}$        &
       $\begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & -0.25 \\
         1 & -0.0891
       \end{vmatrix}$          &        &        &        &         &         \\
4   &         &         &        &        &        &         &
\end{tabular}
\caption[Jury's Table for $Q(z)$]{Jury's Table for $Q(z)$}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```